# Correct way to compress webapi POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a webform page that calls a webapi method to save some data. I am using the HttpClient to make the call and execute the webapi.

I tried to use webAPI compression to post a huge xml to the API.
I basically used these two websites as reference:
http://www.ronaldrosier.net/blog/2013/07/16/implement_compression_in_aspnet_web_api and http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-web-api-compression

The API is working, it is triggering the handler correctly. I am facing some problems trying to compress and post the object, from my webforms on the server side.

Here is the code I tried:

```
bool Error = false;
//Object to post. Just an example...
PostParam testParam = new PostParam()
{
  inputXML = "<xml>HUGE XML</xml>",
  ID = 123
};

try
{
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
       var data = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(PostParam));
       data.WriteObject(memStream, testParam);
       memStream.Position = 0;
       var contentToPost = new StreamContent(this.Compress(memStream));
       contentToPost.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
       contentToPost.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
       var response = client.PostAsync(new Uri("http://myapi/SAVE"), contentToPost).Result;

       var dataReceived = response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

       dynamic results;
       if (dataReceived.IsSuccessStatusCode)
       {
         results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(dataReceived.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
         try
         {
           this.Error = results.errors.Count == 0;
         }
         catch { }
     }
  }
   }
}
catch
{
  this.Error = true;
}


//Compress stream
private MemoryStream Compress(MemoryStream ms)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[ms.Length];
            // Use the newly created memory stream for the compressed data.
            GZipStream compressedzipStream = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, true);
            compressedzipStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            // Close the stream.
            compressedzipStream.Close();
            MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream(buffer);
            return ms1;
        }
```

When I execute the code above, it does not throw any error and in the handler, the request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().result a huge \0\0\0\0\0\0...

Please, can you guys show me what I am doing wrong? How to send the compressed object with the XML to the API correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here's what I came up with. It's possible that since you aren't setting the request to accept gzip encoding, using [HttpClientHandler.AutomaticDecompression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh159009(v=vs.110).aspx), you might be getting back encoded results and aren't handling that. That might not be it though. In any case, I can confirm that this example works. It is one API controller to another. Behind the scenes, I have setup WebApi to accept gzip encoding and decompress it before handing it off to the controller action; this is done by extending the [DelegatingHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh193679(v=vs.110).aspx) class. I let IIS do response compression. I use WebApi 2.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
{
    List<PersonModel> people = new List<PersonModel>
    {
        new PersonModel
        {
            FirstName = "Test",
            LastName = "One",
            Age = 25
        },
        new PersonModel
        {
            FirstName = "Test",
            LastName = "Two",
            Age = 45
        }
    };
    using (HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler())
    {
        handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler, false))
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(people);
            byte[] jsonBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            using (GZipStream gzip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
            {
                gzip.Write(jsonBytes, 0, jsonBytes.Length);
            }
            ms.Position = 0;
            StreamContent content = new StreamContent(ms);
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            content.Headers.ContentEncoding.Add("gzip");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:54425/api/Gzipping", content);
            IEnumerable<PersonModel> results = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<PersonModel>>();
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", results));
        }
    }
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adam! That worked like a charm! I think my mistake was not setting the httpclienthandler and use byte array with json bytes. Anyway, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: GZipStream for this which dll i need to include in application. Because the reference of this GZipStream not found in .

Comment: @A.Goutam It's in System.IO.Compression, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: `MemoryStream ms` should be disposed in above sample

Comment: @fiat MemoryStream certainly has a Dispose method, but it does nearly nothing. As `MemoryStream` is little more than an `Array` implementing `Stream` that has no native/file handles, there's no real harm in not disposing a `MemoryStream`. See https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/memorystream.cs,147

Comment: We had to set the ContentType to `application/octet-stream` in order to get this to work posting to Azure Functions. YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use HttpCompression via IIS
http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpcompression

```
<httpCompression
  directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
<scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
<dynamicTypes>
  <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
  <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
  <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
  <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
</dynamicTypes>
<staticTypes>
  <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
  <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
  <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
  <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
</staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
```

Then the HTTP client must initiate communication for compressed content by sending the appropriate HTTP Accept-encoding header.

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
```

Here is an example:
http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-web-api-compression

Comment: Thanks Carl! Unfortunately, I can't change the applicationHost.config files :(

Comment: What compression is your applicationhost.config supporting?

Comment: BTW, have you seen this solution?  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsapps/en-us/a74324dd-1508-495b-bcd4-0ae99a7ff16d/sending-compressed-content-with-httpclient